# rust polars convert string column to datetime

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-polars, polarssl

I'm trying to learn `rust` and using `polars`. I've a simple CSV file

```
names,pdate,orders
alice,2023-02-12,2
alice,2023-02-18,1
alice,2023-02-22,6
bob,2022-12-10,1
bob,2022-12-14,1
bob,2022-12-30,4
```

I read it in using

```
    let mut df = CsvReader::from_path("t2.csv")
        .unwrap()
        .has_header(true)
        .finish()
        .unwrap();
    println!("{}", df);
```

and it prints out the result as expected. However, I want to cast the column `pdate` into a date to do further date arthimetic with it.  I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73965088/rust-polars-how-to-change-column-value-from-string-to-datetime) by doing so

```
    let dt_options = StrpTimeOptions {
        date_dtype: DataType::Date,
        fmt: Some("%Y-%m-%d".into()),
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let df = df.with_column(col("pdate").str().strptime(dt_options));
```

A `cargo check` gave the following error

```
    Checking test v0.1.0 (/home/xxxx/a1/rustp)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Expr: IntoSeries` is not satisfied
    --> test.rs:37:29
     |
37   |     let df = df.with_column(col("pdate").str().strptime(dt_options));
     |                 ----------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `IntoSeries` is not implemented for `Expr`
     |                 |
     |                 required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `IntoSeries`:
               Arc<(dyn SeriesTrait + 'static)>
               ChunkedArray<T>
               Logical<DateType, Int32Type>
               Logical<DatetimeType, Int64Type>
               Logical<DurationType, Int64Type>
               Logical<TimeType, Int64Type>
               polars::prelude::Series
```

This appears to be a fairly basic functionality, but I've not been able to find a straight solution to this. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
The following code works. But it has a new problem, I'm trying to find the difference between two date columns in days as a float, but it comes out as `Duration`

```
    let df2 = df
        .clone()
        .lazy()
        .with_column(col("pdate").str().strptime(dt_options).alias("dt_pdate"))
        .groupby(["names"])
        .agg([
            col("dt_pdate").shift(1).alias("prev_date"),
            col("orders"),
            col("dt_pdate"),
        ])
        .explode(["prev_date", "orders", "dt_pdate"])
        .select([all(), (col("dt_pdate") - col("prev_date")).alias("delta")])
        .collect()
        .unwrap();
```

Answer (score 2):

At first glance it looks like your df is a DataFrame, not a LazyFrame. You can get a LazyFrame from a DataFrame with `df.lazy()` and a DataFrame from a LazyFrame with `lazy_df.collect()`.

Comment: Thanks ! Made edits, it appears to work. However, it now has a new problem. I'm trying to find the difference between two date columns in days as an integer however it shows up as a ```Duration``` type.

Comment: IIRC, you want to divide by `duration(DurationArgs { days: Some(lit(1)) })`. Note that this takes the floor; if you need float division you may need to do it “manually” (with `map()`, or by casting to float; not sure which is better)